# Reduce the difference between three numbers

Tags: analysis, recreational-mathematics

Is there a way to know the maximum possible reduction between three numbers $(a>b>c)$, so that all three numbers are closer to each other but with the constraint that combined subtraction allowed from the three numbers is limited to a number $'M'$ and combined addition allowed from all three numbers is limited to a number $'N'$.

So for an easy example, if $a=9, b=6, c=5$ and combined addition allowed $(N)=7$ & combined subtraction allowed $(M)=0$ then the three numbers can become $a'=(9+0)=9, b'=(6+3)=9, c'=(5+4)=9$. Which is the closest they can get given the constraints $\rightarrow$  3 was added to $'b'$ and 4 to $'c'$ making the total $(N)=7$.

Can there be a general way to do this for any $(a,b,c)$? Or some analytical formula which can give maximum bound all three numbers will remain within given $M \,\, \& \,\,N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem via linear programming as follows.  Let $M_a, M_b, M_c$ be the amounts added, and let $N_a, N_b, N_c$ be the amounts subtracted.  Let $U$ represent $\max(a',b',c')$ and $L$ represent $\min(a',b',c')$.  The problem is to minimize $U-L$ subject to:
\begin{align}
L \le a + M_a - N_a &\le U \\
L \le b + M_b - N_b &\le U \\
L \le c + M_c - N_c &\le U \\
M_a + M_b + M_c &\le M \\
N_a + N_b + N_c &\le N \\
M_a, M_b, M_c &\ge 0 \\
N_a, N_b, N_c &\ge 0 \\
\end{align}

Comment: Yes this will work. Could there also be any analytical method to just know what will the upper bound for $|\max(a',b',c') - \min(a',b',c')|$ will be in terms of $M,N,a,b \, \& \,c$ without actually solving the optimization problem?

Comment: $\max(a',b',c') \le \max(a,b,c)+M$ and $\min(a',b',c') \ge \min(a,b,c)-N$, so $$\max(a',b',c') - \min(a',b',c') \le \max(a,b,c)+M - \min(a,b,c)+N.$$